# Finding whether two strings are connected in a Hashmap<String, ArrayList<String>> through recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, hashmap, set

The question is asking us to find whether a connection between two airlines are possible. For the input code, they give us the list of airlines and then which airlines are connected to which. I was able to read everything into the scanner and make a Hashmap of String values connecting to a String ArrayList, in order to compensate for duplicating keys. There is no issues with the Hashmap, as after reading out all of the keys and the corresponding values in their ArrayList, everything was matching up.

Here is the printed Hashmap below(some airlines are not listed below because they have no connections, ie: southwest):

```
continental, [america_west, air_china, alaska, air_france, virgin_atlantic]
austrian_airways, [delta]
virgin_atlantic, [air_france]
delta, [swiss_air, austrian_airways, air_canada]
america_west, [mesa, alaska, twa]
```

The issue is calling the recursion in which, given two Strings of Airlines, find if there is a connection. My recursion below is checking whether there is an initial connection between the Airlines, and it not, recursively go inwards. However the error seems to be a Stack Overflow Error. I do not understand why it would overflow
if the test case gives Airlines {"delta" "america_west"},{"continental" "mesa"},{"southwest" "delta"},{"twa" "air_france"}.

```
    public static boolean recur(String a, String b) {
    boolean connection = false;
    
    if(partners.containsKey(a)&&partners.get(a).contains(b)) {return true;}
    
    for(String airlines: (ArrayList<String>)partners.get(a)) {
        if(partners.containsKey(airlines))
            recur(airlines,b);
        }
    
    return connection;
    
}
```

Edit:
I'm sorry I didn't include all of the code, it's my first time uploading, and I felt that it was a bit long.

public class airlinePartners{

```
 static Map<String, ArrayList> partners = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();
 static String returnT = "PARTNERS\n";
 static String returnF = "No miles for you\n";
 int number = 0;

public static void readIn() throws Exception{

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("partners.dat"));
    String[] temp = new String[2];
    int airline = sc.nextInt();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < airline; i++) {
        sc.next();
    }
    int partner = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < partner; i++) {
        temp = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        ArrayList<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(partners.containsKey(temp[0])) {
            partners.get(temp[0]).add(temp[1]);
        }
        else {
        temps.add(temp[1]);
        partners.put(temp[0], temps);
        }
    }
    
    
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList>> i = partners.entrySet().iterator(); 
    while(i.hasNext()){String key = i.next().getKey();
        System.out.println(key+", "+partners.get(key));
    }
    
    
    
    
    int repeat = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    for(int m = 0; m < repeat;m++) {
        temp= sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        //System.out.println(temp[0] + " "+ temp[1]);
        if(recur(temp[0], temp[1])) {
            System.out.println(returnT);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(returnF);
        }
        
    }
    
}

public static boolean recur(String a, String b) {
    boolean connection = false;
    
    if(partners.containsKey(a)&&partners.get(a).contains(b)) {return true;}
    
    for(String airlines: (ArrayList<String>)partners.get(a)) {
        if(partners.containsKey(airlines))
            recur(airlines,b);
        }
    
    return connection;
    
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    new airlinePartners().readIn();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you include the remaining code - where you are calling recur and where you are populating partners Map?

Comment: Your call to recur() does nothing as you ignore its return value.